# set active to li in angular on navigating from each item

Tags: angular

I need to shift the active class from one item of ul to another as one clicks. Please do find my current code below.

```css
.location a {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  color: #666666;
  font-weight: bold; }

.location a:hover{
  background: #29abe2;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px; }

.location a.active{
  background: #29abe2;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px; }

.location a .active-link{
  background: #29abe2;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px; }

#world:target, #nna:target, #ne:target, #nml:target{
  background: #29abe2;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#navigation ul li a:active
{
  background-color: #29abe2;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 location-class location" id="location">
    <ul class="location-ul">
        <li class="active"><a  (click)="worldClick()" id="world">WORLD</a></li>
        <li><a (click)="nnaClick()" id="nna">NNA</a></li>
        <li><a (click)="neClick()" id="ne">NE</a></li>
        <li><a (click)="nmlClick()" id="nml">NML</a></li>
    </ul> 
 </div>
```

Can I do this task with just CSS or should I need JS. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a variable say `activeIndex: number = 0` in your **ts** file.
Use this variable to check the active link on `a` tag and using `[ngClass]` directive apply class `.active` on the `li` element.

```
 <ul class="location-ul">
    <li [ngClass]="{'active': activeIndex === 0}"><a (click)="worldClick(); activeIndex = 0" id="world">WORLD</a></li>
    <li [ngClass]="{'active': activeIndex === 1}"><a (click)="nnaClick(); activeIndex = 1" id="nna">NNA</a></li>
    <li [ngClass]="{'active': activeIndex === 2}"><a (click)="neClick(); activeIndex = 2" id="ne">NE</a></li>
    <li [ngClass]="{'active': activeIndex === 3}"><a (click)="nmlClick(); activeIndex = 3" id="nml">NML</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create a reference variable to identify which nav item is clicked. No need to define multiple functions just one function is enough.

Use ternary operator in the ngClass directive to match the **selectedNavItem** variable.

Please refer below code.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  navActive = false;
  selectedNavItem: string;

  navClick(navId) {
    this.selectedNavItem = navId;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 location-class location" id="location">
    <ul class="location-ul">
        <li [ngClass]="(selectedNavItem == 'world')? 'active': ''"><a  (click)="navClick('world')" id="world">WORLD</a></li>
        <li [ngClass]="(selectedNavItem == 'nna')? 'active': ''"><a (click)="navClick('nna')" id="nna">NNA</a></li>
        <li [ngClass]="(selectedNavItem == 'ne')? 'active': ''"><a (click)="navClick('ne')" id="ne">NE</a></li>
        <li [ngClass]="(selectedNavItem == 'nml')? 'active': ''"><a (click)="navClick('nml')" id="nml">NML</a></li>

      </ul>  
 </div>
```